# Debug and release configurations in a java netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to have some sort of debug/release configurations that I can chose between so i can have some variables altered when compiling my project?

For example, alternate between database login variables or turn off some output debug variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of configuration is easily handled via command-line `-D` parameters, which should be settable in the run configurations, or via configuration files which can be selected the same way (usually cleaner, if there's a bunch of parameters).

Depending on frameworks in use there are also multiple ways to handle this.

Answer (score 6):

For Java projects in NetBeans, you can create multiple configurations.  Right click the project in the `Projects` window, choose `Set Configuration > Customize`.  In the top right of the new window, for `Configuration`, choose `New...`.  Give the new configuration a name and click OK.  Now you can set different command line switches (`Arguments`) and `VM Options` for the new configuration.

Any configuration that you create here you can then choose from the project's context menu (right click, select `Set Configuration > MyConfig`).

Comment: This is really the correct answer and should be marked as such.

Comment: It seems that the configurations only control arguments and vm options and not compile flags like "Generate Debugging Info"

Comment: Run-time configuration is possible but what about build-time? I have not yet figured out a way to include different libraries / jars for different configurations. I like to use the same project under MS Windows as well as under Linux with their respective build-time configurations.

Comment: I think I solved my problem.  Add a configuration (project properties / Set Configuration). That creates a file inside the configs folder with the name of the new configuration + .properties. It should contain one property, the main class (if you entered one in the configuration pop-up window which you should). Now you can add your properties and refer to them from project.properties. In my case I added paths for the jars:    reference.jnavisa.jar=lib/linux64/JnaVisa64.jar
reference.visa.dll=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: @Günter I am facing the same problem, but in my case, I need to use different src/main/resources/application.yml depending on the build. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't know but I would think the same principle applies: Create a reference variable / property which assigns different values / paths in the respective configuration .properties files. Then, in the main build file, point to the reference variable instead of a hard-coded path / file.